The data file of the LISA Interferometer results
How to extract the data of the strain versus frequency plot of the Laser Interferometer Space Antenna (LISA): Figure (2) in this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00786
The paper doesn't contain any table for that plot.
Also for experts in gravitational waves, may I ask what is the relation between the energy density of the gravitational waves $\Omega$ and the strain $Hz^{-1/2}$ which is plotted versus frequency in Figure (2).

Ask the authors for the relevant data? Or check the public LIGO Document Cotnrol Center

For the general problem of getting data from a published plot, you can use WebPlotDigitizer

Many thanks @sten
